# Timed Line Drawing

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, graphics-programming, linear-algebra, projectile-physics

I'm trying to program a remake of the classic Missile Command Atari game from scratch, but I've run into a problem. So I have a function that can draw a line from one point to another. I figured I could use this for the missiles and meteors by having them drawn from their initial position to their current position, and then update their current position each time I render.

This works in the sense that I can see exactly what I want to be graphically rendered, but the issue is that the speeds are either too fast or slow. As the missiles/meteors become closer to falling/rising at a verticle slope, they are drawn almost instantaneously. On the other hand, as they have a slope closer to being y=x, they are drawn slower and slower. Can someone help me out?
Here is my code for how I update the position each render:
(initX/Y is initial position, x/y are current position, destX/Y is the destination position)

```
float dx = destX - initX;
float dy = destY - initY;
if (initX > destX) x -= speed;
else x += speed;
y = initY + dy * (x - initX) / dx;
```

Comment: Dividing by almost 0 gives you incredibly high values. For almost vertical lines, dx is almost 0. It would make more sense to me to make a vector 'direction', which would be float2(dx,dy), normalize that, and draw your missile or line or whatever at direction *speed.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly. Also thank you for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

This is simply combining three formulas
Speed = dist/time
pythagarus a^2 = B^2 + c^2
and y = mx + c

1. So dist moved each time is speed * time
   You define a speed for your object, the time is timediff between last update and this one
2. y = mx + c. Ignore C since don't care about where it might cross the x axis
   So y = mx
   So m (gradient) is ydiff/xdiff
   ydiff = starty - endy
   xdiff = startx - endx
3. Now this is where we combine.

   The dist is the hypotinuse of the right angled triangle
   so Dist^2 = x^2 + y^2,

   from above y = mx
   so dist^2 = x^2 + (mx)^2
   Play around with algebra to get
   dist^2 = x^2 + m^2x^2
   so dist^2 = x^2(1 + m^2)
   x^2 = dist^2/(1+m^2)
   x = sqrt(dist^2/(1+m^2))

SO
get start and endpoint and calc gradient 'm'
for time diff since last call
calc distance
then calc x increment as above
calc y increment y=mx
latestx+= x inc
latesty+= yinc
new line is from startx,y to latestposnx,y

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the same mathematical apparatus, but add additional functions in the functions that would average the values vertically and horizontally.

Comment: It is really not clear what you mean. Perhaps giving examples of code or algorithm would help explain what you mean.